# Messenger Platform SQL Database access

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm having trouble in this, i want to return the value of item_name.

```
$productnum = "1001";

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "ewconline_db_user", "steve030405", "ewconline_db");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `shop_products` WHERE `item_id` = '$productnum' ");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $item_name = $row['item_name'];

    $response = "{
                    'recipient':{
                        'id': $senderId
                        },
                    'message':{
                        'text': $item_name
                    }
                }";
```

it doesn't seem to get the value and sends a reply back to user.

and if i run the sql program on different url. it works perfectly fine.

Comment: you can try with  $item_name = $row[0]['item_name']

Comment: sir? it still doesnt work.

Comment: Don’t create JSON “manually” in string form. Create the proper data structure, and then use json_encode. _“and if i run the sql program on different url. it works perfectly fine.”_ - well then do some proper debugging …?

Comment: WTH!. it works sir. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK!. Don’t create JSON “manually” in string form. Create the proper data structure, and then use json_encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "ewconline_db_user", "steve030405", "ewconline_db");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `shop_products` WHERE `item_id` = '".$productnum."'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$answer = $row['item_name'];

$response = [
    'recipient' => [ 'id' => $senderId ],
    'message' => [ 'text' => $answer ]
];
```

I have done it like this, and it works.

and used json_encode($response);

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $item_name = $row['item_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always check if your connection succeeded to begin with. So after you construct your mysqli instance, add something like this:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Database connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die(); // or throw an exception or whatever
}
```

This should tell you why are not getting your expected result.